# Software to condense video down to a few minutes by merging moving objects and static background?

Tags: video-editing

Take a look at this video:

[Rush hour intersection traffic condensed into one minute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufK2XRGUjuc)

I understand the principle behind how this video was created. A static camera was used, and thus by using temporal analysis you can get a static full-screen background. Against this background we also track and isolate all moving objects, and then finally we merge moving objects on top of the background to create a much shorter fluid shot that appears to be the intersection from hell.

I've seen similar software that can take a days worth of surveillance footage and condense it automatically, but of course now that I want to take a look at such a program I cannot find it. I understand that any such program that does it automatically will not be able to match the quality of the video linked above. Just consider the video an example of what I am looking for.

The question is, does any such software packages exists on the open market? Open source, closed source, free, non-free, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

One open source solution that will require a little effort on your part would be to use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), if you don't wish to use a C++ compiler and all the fun and games that involves I suggest that you use the [Python](https://www.python.org/) bindings.

OpenCV is:

- Free, Gratis and Open Source
- Cross Platform Linux, Windows, OS-X & more
- Available pre-built for Windows
- Provides a lot of tools for image and video processing
- Can be used to develop tools/utilities in C++ or python.

Python is:

- Free, Gratis and Open Source
- Cross Platform Linux, Windows, OS-X & more
- Available pre-built for Windows, *usually already installed on the rest.*
- Quick to start learning
- Works interactivly - no need to compile code.
- Small

Both have a lot of online support available including [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), *(at the time of writing the number of questions tagged [Python]=656,941 [OpenCV]=34,430 & [opencv][python]=5,244)* so you will not be alone.

### Your starter for 10

The following python code, shamelessly lifted from [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/mog-background-reduction-python-opencv-tutorial/), will show two video windows with the background subtracted in the second.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('people-walking.mp4')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('fgmask',frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)


    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: I know there are good libraries, like OpenCV and Emgu CV that can be used to create such a program, but I believe I've seen existing software that does this already.